# Can i do a callback (or something similar) after a filter function?

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a restful api to do stuff just with a local file:

**data.js**:

```js
let store = {
  posts: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Top 10 ES6 Features every Web Developer must know',
      url: 'https://webapplog.com/es6',
      text: "This essay will give you a quick introduction to ES6. If you don’t know what is ES6, it’s a new JavaScript implementation.",
      comments: [
        { text: 'Cruel…..var { house, mouse} = No type optimization at all' },
        { text: 'I think you’re undervaluing the benefit of ‘let’ and ‘const’.' },
        { text: '(p1,p2)=>{ … } ,i understand this ,thank you !' }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'anotherPost',
      url: 'https://webapplog.com/es6',
      text: "This essay will give you a quick introduction to ES6. If you don’t know what is ES6, it’s a new JavaScript implementation.",
      comments: [
        { text: 'Cruel…..var { house, mouse} = No type optimization at all' },
        { text: 'I think you’re undervaluing the benefit of ‘let’ and ‘const’.' },
        { text: '(p1,p2)=>{ … } ,i understand this ,thank you !' }
      ]
    }

  ]
}
module.exports = store;
```

For example here´s how I do a Post request to create another `post`:

```js
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
        data.posts.push({
            id: req.body.id,
            name: req.body.name,
            url: req.body.url,
            text: req.body.text,
            comments: [
                req.body.comments
            ]
          })
        res.send(data.posts)
    })
```

Or here´s how I delete a post (i actually add it the id property in order to do this, although minutes later i found out it wasn´t neccesary, but because of it it wasn´t the reason it came up the creation of this question)

```js
router.delete('/:postId', (req, res) => {
        const post_id = req.body.id;
        const index = post_id -1;

        data.posts.splice(index, 1);
        res.send(data.posts)
    })
```

So when I try to do the put route i came up with this, although later i also found out i could just use `data.posts[index].name = etc...` but I decided to open this question because i have really curiosity in how something can this could work (obviously something similar since the following code does not work):

```js
 data.posts.filter(post => {
            post.id === req.params.postId;
        }).then(post => {
            post.id = req.body.id,
            post.name = req.body.name,
            post.url = req.body.url,
            post.text = req.body.text,
            post.comments = [
                req.body.comments
            ]
        })
```

What am trying to do there is once the correct post has been filtered, then modify the properties of that post. I´ve been doing javascript for months but i have always been blindly following tutorials and never stop to actually learn how callbacks work or how that code is not possible. But because i see similar code to work (callbacks in express), i was wondering if somebody could give some direction.

As i said i already have the simple solution sorted it out but i am very curious in how i could so something like that with the filter function (or just educate me in how this things works)

Comment: Doesn't `filter` give you back an array? You should use `find`. This will give you one result (not in an array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Array#filter` method is synchronous and returns the filtered array, you can chain the `Array#map` function to it in order to transform the elements of the filtered array. There's no need for a "callback" or promise in the sense that the code is all synchronous ... for iterative methods like map and filter, the function argument is typically called an "iteratee".

So for your last code block, you can simply do something like this:

```
const filteredAndModifiedPosts = data.posts.filter(post => {
  return post.id === req.params.postId;
}).map(post => {
  post.id = req.body.id,
  post.name = req.body.name,
  post.url = req.body.url,
  post.text = req.body.text,
  post.comments = [
    req.body.comments
  ]
  return post
})
```

Comment: There is actually an error in your code example. Since you are using brackets around the body of the arrow function you are passing to the `filter()` method, you are not returning anything there (or, better said returning `undefined`).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I copy pasted the code from OP and didn’t notice that. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First - you could use `find()` method instead of `filter()` method to find a single element in an array. `filter()` returns a new array of elements that satisfied your testing function, while `find()` returns a single element - the first one that satisfied the testing function. You can see the difference on this basic example:

```
data.posts.filter(post => post.id === req.params.postId); // [{id: 123}, ...]
data.posts.find(post => post.id === req.params.postId); // {id: 123}
```

Next - you are using the `then()` function incorrectly, because you are trying to apply it to the result of the `filter()` function call, which is, as I explained already, an `Array` not a `Promise`. Here, you seem to belive the `filter()` function is asynchronous, but that is incorrect. So what you could simply do to find your desired post and then change its properties is this:

```
const post = data.posts.find(post => post.id === req.params.postId);
post.id = req.body.id;
post.name = req.body.name;
post.url = req.body.url;
post.text = req.body.text;
post.comments = req.body.comments;
```